# Calculate person age from PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a PHP form which includes 3 fields for person birthday:
iBirthday, iBirthMonth (int 1 thru 12), and iBirthYear (int 4 digits)

I am trying to calculate if the person is older than 18 years, when pressing submit, before running the SQL INSERT.

How can i calculate this? I have no idea how to concatenate these 3 int into a date, and compare to current date.

I have some tests that work, for example

```
//Check if gender is NULL 
if ($iGender == '') { 
$sTopError = gettext('Did not select Gender'); 
$bErrorFlag = true; 
}
```

I would like to do a similar test, that says: "Person not above 18 years".

Comment: http://php.net/mktime

Answer (score -1):

This function will return amount of years from given date in YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
function get_age($date)
{
    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    $today  = new DateTime($today);
    $date   = new DateTime($date);

    $diff = $date->diff($today)->format("%Y");

    return (int)$diff;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo get_age('2000-02-01');
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.